# Why I can't see response Value in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, networking

I'm a beginner of `iOS`. I'm getting a `response` through network communication now. Currently, my code has been debugged, but it does not fall into the `catch`.

**post function**

```swift
    func post(url: URL, body: NSMutableDictionary, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) throws {

        var postRequest: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        postRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        postRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        postRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        postRequest.addValue("*******", forHTTPHeaderField: "api_key")
        postRequest.addValue("*******", forHTTPHeaderField: "game_key")
        postRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        session.dataTask(with: postRequest, completionHandler: completionHandler).resume()

    }
```

**call function**

```swift
    @IBAction func nextScreen(_ sender: Any) {
        if self.nickField.text!.count > 12 {
            callAlert(DacAlert.overNickname.alertResult!)
        } else {

            let url: URL = URL(string: globalUrl.apiAddress + globalUrl.ApiValue + globalUrl.ApiValueSecond2)!
            let body: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()


            Address = LocalStorage.get("Address") as? String

            body.setValue(self.nickField.text!, forKey: "new_nickname")
            body.setValue(Address, forKey: "address")

            do {
                try globalUrl.post(url: url, body: body, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                    Log.Debug("**********************************************")
                    Log.Debug(response)
                    Log.Debug("**********************************************")
                    Log.Debug(data)
                    Log.Debug("**********************************************")
                    Log.Debug(error)
                    Log.Debug("**********************************************")
                })
            } catch {
                Log.Debug("**********************************************")
                print(error)
            }

        }
    }
```

I can't check any value.

Thanks in advance

**************************** Edit ***********************************

Ah, I was doing Debug wrong. I could see the data values. But the value is byte. Unable to view the actual value.

**Log**

---

72 bytes //  Log.Debug(data)

Log.Debug(response)

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600003aa8420> { URL: http://11.111.111.11:8080/***** } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Fri, 13 Sep 2019 16:03:40 GMT"
    );
    "Set-Cookie" =     (
        "JSESSIONID=F8CC56CA656E11CB7EEA7B51D8D3810E; Path=/; HttpOnly"
    );
    "Transfer-Encoding" =     (
        Identity
    );
} }
```

---

**normal response value**

```
{
    "result": "test",
    "resultCode": "Sucess",
    "resultMsg": "Membership nickname change succeeded."
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: you have to debug the data in another formar, so if you use codable you log the response of the decode, data is just data in bytes format so don't expect to debug it.

Comment: Hi @kjoe  How can I debug?

Comment: your answer was exactly what i meant so vote up for you

Comment: @kjoe Thanks you so much. By the way, Could you tell me what to do to use formdata?

Comment: there are lot of answer in here about how to use formData. in swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the data by making JSON.

```swift
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
    Log.Debug(json)
} catch {
    Log.Error(error)
}
```